# Find indices of unordered pairs of rows satisfying some constraints

Tags: arrays, matlab, filter

I have two vectors `U1` and `U2` in Matlab of dimension `9x1` both listing the integers from `1` to `9`.

```
clear
U1=(1:1:9).';
U2=U1;
```

I then construct the vector `U` of size `(9*9)x1` by taking the Cartesian product of `U1` and `U2`

```
[ca, cb] = ndgrid(U1, U2);
U=[ca(:) cb(:)];
```

Basically, the structure of `U` is

```
  U=[1 1;
     2 1;
     ...;
     9 1;
     ---;
     1 2;
     ...
     9 2;
     ---;
     ...
     9 9]
```

Now, I would like your help to construct a vector `ind` listing the row indices of the unordered pairs of rows of `U` such that:

**(*)** `i~=k` and `j~=l` where `[i,j]`, `[k,l]` are the two rows from `U` considered

I wrote a piece of code that does what I want but it doesn't seem to me very efficient because of step 1) below. Could you help to improve?

Step 1) Take the row indices of **ALL** unordered pairs of rows from `U`

```
ind_temp=nchoosek([1:1:9^2], 2); %3240x2
```

Step 2) Delete from `ind_temp` the row indices that do not satisfy **(*)**

```
ind=cell(size(ind_temp,1),1);
for p=1:size(ind,1)
    if U(ind_temp(p,1),1)~=U(ind_temp(p,2),1) && ...
       U(ind_temp(p,1),2)~=U(ind_temp(p,2),2)
       ind{p}=ind_temp(p,:);
    end
end
ind=vertcat(ind{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use a for loop here. Alternatively you can calculate the hamming distance between all rows in `U`. The hamming distance is the percentage of differing coordinates, so if neither of the two values in the row match the hamming distance will equal 1.

```
d = squareform(pdist(U,'hamming')); % Hamming distance between all rows
d = triu(d); % Set all values below the diagonal to 0, so we don't get [1 2] and [2 1] in ind.
[q,w] = find(d==1); % q and w will be row/column of all d==1 values.
ind = [q w]; % Assemble ind
ind = sortrows(ind); % Only necessary to sort rows if you want results exactly matching your example
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straight-forward to vectorize this code (vectorizing usually means removing loops). For example, `U(ind_temp(:,1),:)` is a matrix with pairs taken from `U`, but repeated and ordered according to the values in the first column of `ind_temp`. We can repeat that operation for the second column, and directly compare all pairs:

```
I = all(U(ind_temp(:,1),:) ~= U(ind_temp(:,2),:),2);
```

Now `I` is a logical array with the same length as `ind_temp` (3240x1) indicating for which of the pairs in `ind_temp` the constraint is satisfied. We can use this to index into `ind_temp` as follows:

```
ind = ind_temp(I,:);
```

On Octave, this vectorized code was about 3 orders of magnitude faster than the original code. On MATLAB the difference will not be as dramatic, but it should still be significantly faster.